# JS: check if elem in array is File object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array which holds ids (as strings) and File objects. After submitting form I need to filter this array and get only File objects.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: A good start to your question would be to show - An example of this array and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate through the array and check each elements data type.

```
array.forEach(function(element) {
    if(typeof element == 'object') {
        newArray.push(element);
    }
});
```